# Dynamically importing a module that is specified at runtime from a compiled output

Tags: python, bash, import, clojure, module

## Overview

I have a project in which I have created a simple clojure compiler that converts clojure code to python code (this will be uploaded to clojars). Separately, I have a python project that will be packaged and made pip installable. I am yet to fully package both, although they are almost ready to be.

## The problem

The user specifies a model in clojure, that model is then compiled to python, where the output is `<user_model_name>.py`, this output has a class structure. Then, the python package that I have takes that python output and extracts the methods from that python output and performs inference on that model. However, it is my first time doing a project like this and so I am in desperate need of pointers with how to actually find the compiled file, given some file path (maybe) (preferably just the model name) and then load that model in at runtime within the python code.

Locally, it is very easy to do this with the `importlib module` as I know how to direct my code to the output. But, once both packages are installed on the system I am really not sure what the best way to go about doing this is.

## The aim

The end goal is to have something like this:

The user writes a model:

    `(def if-model
     (foppl-query
       (let [x1 (sample (normal 0 1))
            x2 (sample (normal 0 1))]
         (if (> x1 0)
          (observe (normal x2 1) 1)
          (observe (normal -1 1) 1))
         x1)))`

Then in the terminal calls:

`lein exec compiler.clj -p if-model.clj`

Then the user would write a script that calls the python package:

`import ...
from <python_package> import inference as infer`


`<user defined parameters> 
...
run_alg  = infer.<inference_obj>(<filename or Path to module>, other_params)`

(Path to file is maybe too much to ask for the end user)

The import needs to happen within the `<inference_obj>()` at run time, which is an instantiation of an inference algorithm that requires the model class.

I've googled high and low, and I assume that I would have to use the `importlib` library to create a finder and loader, but I am not entirely sure how to do this for this problem. 
A second approach, although I am not sure if this would be possible, is to use the `subprocess` module in python and to write a bash script inside a python module, within my python package, that calls the clojure compiler on the `<user_model_name>.clj` and then sets some global PATH variable to where the compiled output is, so the `<python_package>` knows where to look. So something like this in the terminal, `python python_bash_script.py <user_model_name>.clj` . But again, I am really not sure and so any pointers would be much appreciated.

Thanks for taking the time to read my question.

Answer (score 2):

Although I don't have direct answer to your question, let me comment on some details.

Using `importlib` would be the easiest choice I believe. Once you've imported such a generated module on the top of the file, it's clearly obvious wether you've loaded it successfully or not.

When generating Python code, the result could be just a function I suppose because your Clojure code also has a function.

If Python is the main part of your project, take a look at [Hy language](https://github.com/hylang/hy). It's a clone of Clojure language implemented with pure Python. Most of the clojure.core functions, immutable data structures and other stuff are there.

Perhaps you would be able to skip Clojure in your project writing some bits of Clojure code in Hy.

Also, in your examples, you run Clojure compiler within `lein` utility plus `exec` plugin. If you want to distribute that Clojure compiler, it should be just uberjar.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It isn't just the compiler written in clojure, there is an additional language that we have written that is based on clojure syntax, which I haven't explained above. This has certain semantic qualities that preserve certain technicalities that we need to ensure, so that the validity and structure of the models that are written are legitimate.
Thanks for the uberjar advice, that is super useful.